# Removing .php extension in localhost

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've been trying to figure out how to remove .php extension, I've searched everywhere and it seems most of the code are not working anymore. The code below is what I am using now to remove the .php extension but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !- f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: Your second line says "*only do the following if the file doesn't exist*".

Comment: and where did you put the code above?

Comment: Above of what? It is my entire code in .htaccess

Comment: This .htaccess code works prefectly


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628001/removing-html-url-extension-using-htaccess-not-working

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **XAMPP** on Windows 10. I also tried many times to remove the **`.php`** extension but the result was the same. But after a long while finally, I got how we can do this. If you want the same results, just follow the steps given below...

To remove the **`.php`** extension from a PHP file, e.g. if you want to change **`mywebsite.com/about.php`** to **`mywebsite.com/about`** you have to add the following code inside your **`.htaccess`** file:

First of all, make sure you've created a new file named **`.htaccess`** and placed it at your **`root-level/root-directory`** where your **`index`** file is placed.
Now, open this (.htaccess) file with any editor of your choice, copy/paste the given code and save it...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, if you (any user) will access **`mywebsite.com/about`** in the browser, the user will see the content of **`mywebsite.com/about.php`** page.

But still, if you (any user) will access the URL as **`mywebsite.com/about.php`**, this will not redirect the user to this **`mywebsite.com/about`** page. But will go to this **`mywebsite.com/about.php`** page which means the user can still visit **`mywebsite.com/about.php`** page. Don't worry about it. If you want to avoid this, you can simply follow the next step.

To avoid the above problem, now you need to add some more rules in the **`.htaccess`** file. For this, you've to replace your old code with this new one given below, save your file and check it out...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

That's all and you're all set.
I hope this will fix everyone's problem.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Kindly visit this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050795/15639663 ... if you want to know how to remove the **`.html`** extension.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the .php extension from a PHP file

for example `yoursite.com/wallpaper.php` to `yoursite.com/wallpaper` you have to add the following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L, QSA]
```

Or

see [removing .php extension from URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/526153/removing-php-extension-with-htaccess-does-not-work)

Also, make sure that you've mod_rewrite on.

Also see [how to create .htacess file](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?)

Comment: It is still not working, I get an error "The requested URL "http://localhost/series3/list" cannot be found or is not available. "

Comment: make sure that you've mod_rewrite is on.

Comment: How do I change it to on?

Comment: see [How to enable mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: It is still not working I get the following error "The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Here is my full code <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

Comment: @Bono did you checked is mod_rewrite is enabled or not ?

Comment: I added RewriteEngine On to enable the mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change internal website coding as well with htaccess code above and remove the file name URL extension from where it is mentioned in your web coding.
Eg:-

> https://yoursite.com/page.html

changed to

> https://yoursite.com/page/

htaccess code

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

This one works especially if you wanted to remove the .php from the url and redirect the user to the non .php url without changing or removing the .php in a url or inside the href:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Although, if you are using an ajax and fetch, you might need to remove .php on it, which is what I did.