# removing .html URL extension using .htaccess not working

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the below code to remove .html extention form url, but it is not working..

can any one help , where i have to put the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Comment: What is the URL you're attempting? Currently that will only match up to the first `/`, so if you're `attempting/this/file` the rewrite will try `attempting.html`

Comment: Have you restart your server

Comment: @arco444 I'm using only www.sitename.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you, but that is not working. where i have to place the .htaccess file. i copied that file in public_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I Got the correct .HTACCESS code to remove .php extention... :)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: You asked to remove `.html` extension in question and answering your question for removing `.php` extension.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share an understandable, simple way to remove the **`.html`** extension from the URL using the **`.htaccess`** file. I'm using **XAMPP** on Windows 10. For me, it's working perfectly. If you want the same result, just follow the steps given below...

For removing the **`.html`** extension, e.g. if you want to change **`mywebsite.com/contact.html`** to **`mywebsite.com/contact`** you have to add the following code inside your **`.htaccess`** file:

First of all, create a new file named **`.htaccess`** and placed it at your **`root-directory`** where your **`index`** file is placed.
Now, open this (**.htaccess**) file with any editor of your choice and write/copy/paste the given code in your file and save it...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Now, if you (any user) will access **`mywebsite.com/contact`** in the browser, it will show the content of **`mywebsite.com/contact.html`** page.

So, what if any user will access the URL as **`mywebsite.com/contact.html`**? this will redirect the user to this **`mywebsite.com/contact.html`** page instead of this **`mywebsite.com/contact`** which means the user can still visit the **`mywebsite.com/contact.html`** page. Don't worry about it. If you want to avoid this, the next step is for you...

To avoid the above problem and for redirecting users to the newly created URL, you need to add some more rules in your **`.htaccess`** file. So, open it again and replace your old code with the new one given below and save your file...(You can ignore this step, It's on you...)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Now, you're all set.
I hope this will fix everyone's problem.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Kindly visit this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050563/15639663 ... if you want to know how to remove the **`.php`** extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```